scale_y_continuous makes graph go missing
I want to create a bar chart that has a year, value and a category dimension. The x-axis should be the different years and within a single year, I want the bars to be in ascending order.
I manage to do it, but when I try to change scale_y_continuous-parameter, all hell breaks loose and no graph is displayed.
Below, I demonstrate the problem with sample data. The first graph is exactly what I want, except for the y-axis. I want to be able to adjust the y-axis (ticks, text, etc.). But as said, when I try to adjust it, the code stops working.
Sample code
# Example data
df <- data.frame(type = c("cat1", "cat1", "cat2", "cat2"),
                 year = c(1,2,1,2),
                 val  = c(100,70,60,100))

library(ggplot2)

# basic plot works
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = reorder(val, as.factor(year)), fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.6)

# doesnt work... why??
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = reorder(val, as.factor(year)), fill = type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0.03, 0.11)),  
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
    limits = c(0, max(df$val, na.rm = FALSE) + 10) )


The issue is that you convert your numeric variable val to a factor using reorder(val, as.factor(year)). Not sure what you are trying to achieve with that. Simply use y = val and you are fine.

@stefan Sorry, but i'm not sure I understood. When running ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = val, fill = type)) +   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.6), the resulting graph is not ascending in order. With the factoring, I am able to get the right order of bars that I want - but then I have the issue with the options.

@BenBolker Hej Ben. Would suggest to undelete your answer as you explained the issue pretty well. Concerning the changed order: As you already guessed ... this is due to the fact that the grouping and hence the order is based on the interaction of all discrete variables. To get the desired order when using y = val we can use e.g. df <- df |> arrange(year, val) |> mutate(group = forcats::fct_inorder(paste0(year, type))) and add group = group to the aes().

That's a nice ordering trick, I may use it for other things in the future ...

Your original plot is treating val as a factor, which is quite unusual/strange: the values are internally being converted to integer values {1, 2, 3}, which is what's actually being plotted along with the factor labels {60, 70, 100}. This means that the distance between 60 and 70 on the y-axis is the same as the distance between 70 and 100 — a strange graphical design decision at best, and misleading at worst:

If, as @stefan suggests, you use your second bit of code with y=val rather than making y into a factor, and use tidyverse tools to make a new variable that defines your ordering, you can get something more sensible ...
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df |> arrange(year, val) |> mutate(group = forcats::fct_inorder(paste0(year, type)))
ggplot(df2, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = val, fill = type, group = group)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge(0.7), width = 0.6) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(0.03, 0.11)),  
    breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10), 
    limits = c(0, max(df$val, na.rm = FALSE) + 10) )



May I still ask why is it that the val is being treated as a factor? Is it the command reorder(val, as.factor(year). If so, this still seems weird to me, for I am specifying to treat the year as a factor variable.

Yes. reorder() always returns a factor.
